# Gesture recognization in iOS programming

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, gesture-recognition

How to do simple gesture recognization in iOS programming using cocos2d? Gesture simply means the path of your finger when you swipe the screen.

I want to use some simple gestures in my game when user touches the screen, such as lines(eight directions), circles, squares, and other gestures like 'V', '^', '<', '>'. Is there any easy way to recognization the user input quickly?

Answer (score 3):

iOS SDK 3.2 introduced the `UIGestureRecognizer` class for simple recognition of simple gestures.

The concrete subclasses of `UIGestureRecognizer` are the following:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer
UIPinchGestureRecognizer
UIRotationGestureRecognizer
UISwipeGestureRecognizer
UIPanGestureRecognizer
UILongPressGestureRecognizer
```

If you need to recognize additional gestures you can try sublassing UIGestureRecognizer, for example a "check mark" gesture. See subclassing notes in Apple's reference docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will have a try later.

Answer (score 1):

Try following link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_4_Gesture_Recognition_Tutorial_(Xcode_4)
which describes gesture recognition.

and also try for it:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
[recognizer release];
```